# Solve the recursion equation using probability generating functions.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $\{X_{n},n\geq 1\}$ independent and identically distributed random variables with $P\left[X_{1}=1 \right]=p=1-P\left[X_{1}=0\right]$. Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ be a random walk on $\{0,1,2,..\}$ that can either make one step to the right or stay in its current state and that it starts at state 0.
For $n\geq 0$ and $1\geq k \geq n+1$, $$P[S_{n+1}=k]=pP[S_{n}=k-1]+(1-p)P[S_{n}=k].$$ Solve the recursion equation using generating functions.

Hello, I am trying to solve this class example as my professor said and he mentioned that the solution is the binomial distribution. Can someone explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  You have stated $X_k$ are iid bernoulis and $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$... this binomially distributed in essence by definition.  If you want to compute the MGF of $S_n$ to confirm you can.

Comment: This is not a "random walk."

Comment: @Math1000 why not? A general random walk is of the form $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ where the $X_k$ are i.i.d, that's the case here.

Comment: I'd say it's a discrete-time pure birth process with jumps of size $+1$ and jump times i.i.d. with geometric distribution. Typically when you say "random walk" there is a possibility of returning to the initial state after leaving it, which is not the case here.

Comment: Typically when you say "random walk" it has to fulfil the definition of a random walk, that's the case here. It's ok if you don't want to call it like this… but then you should not claim to the author it's not a random walk. If it fits to the definition, it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiplying your recurrence relation by $\ x^k\ $, and summing from $\ k=1\ $ to infinity gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^kP\left[S_{n+1}=k\right]&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty px^k P\left[S_n=k-1\right]+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)x^k P\left[S_n=k\right]\\
&=px \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}P\left[S_n=k-1\right]+ (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^kP\left[S_n=k\right]\\
&= px \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^kP\left[S_n=k\right]+ (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^kP\left[S_n=k\right]\ .
\end{align}
Definining $\ \phi_n(x)= \sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty x^kP\left[S_n=k\right]\ $, this equation can be written as
$$
\phi_{n+1}(x)-P\left[S_{n+1}=0\right]=px\phi_n(x)+(1-p)\left(\phi_n(x)-P\left[S_n=0\right]\right)\ ,
$$
or
$$
\phi_{n+1}(x)=\left(px+1-p\right)\phi_n(x)\ ,
$$
because $\ P\left[S_{n+1}=0\right]=(1-p)^{n+1}=(1-p) P\left[S_n=0\right]\ $. This recursion has the solution $\ \phi_n(x)=(1-p+px)^{n-1}\phi_1(x)\ $, and since $\ \phi_1(x)=(1-p) +px\ $, we end up with
$$
\phi_n(x)= (1-p+px)^n\ .
$$
What is the coefficient of $\ x^k\ $ in $\ (1-p+px)^n\ $?